# Unable to read/write to Google Sheets from a deployed Cloud Function using google.auth.default credentials

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I want to use a Google Cloud Function to read/write to a Google Sheet using the Google Drive API. I've tried deploying the code below as a Cloud Function (triggered by a Pub/Sub):

```
def hello_pubsub(event, context):
    from googleapiclient.discovery import build
    import google.auth

    credentials, project_id = google.auth.default(scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets'])

    service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=credentials)
    spreadsheet_id = 'my_spreadsheet_id_goes_here'

    # Call the Sheets API
    sheet = service.spreadsheets()
    result = sheet.values().get(spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id,range="A1:B4").execute()
    values = result.get('values', [])
    for value in values:
        print(value)

    range_ = 'A7'
    request = service.spreadsheets().values().append(spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id, range=range_, valueInputOption='RAW', insertDataOption='OVERWRITE', body={"values":[['test cell input']]})
    response = request.execute()
    print(response)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    hello_pubsub('a', 'b')
```

I'm getting several errors in Google Cloud Platform > Logging:
file_cache is unavailable when using oauth2client >= 4.0.0
File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google_api_python_client-1.8.0-py3.7.egg/googleapiclient/discovery_cache/**init**.py", line 36, in autodetect
from google.appengine.api import memcache ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google.appengine'

I can run this same script locally from Terminal and it works perfectly.

Any help or ideas are appreciated. Again, I want to read/write to a Google Sheet from a Cloud Function. It is my own Google Sheet run through the same Google Cloud account.

Comment: What is your `requirements.txt` file?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere empty, I'm not sure what it should contain since I don't see 'googleapiclient' or 'google' in pip freeze

Comment: I answered for being clearer with a good text formatting. let me know if it works.

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question, I was deploying the Cloud Function wrong. 
To have it work correctly, I had to put my function main.py, requirements.txt and my service_account.json in the same folder, then deploy it from Terminal.

There are two ways I found to read/write to a sheet:

```
# METHOD 1 -- using googleapiclient.discovery.build
def hello_pubsub(event, context):
    from googleapiclient.discovery import build
    import google.auth

    credentials, project_id = google.auth.default(scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets'])
    service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=None)
    spreadsheet_id = 'redacted'
    # Call the Sheets API
    sheet = service.spreadsheets()
    result = sheet.values().get(spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id,range="A1:B4").execute()
    values = result.get('values', [])
    # Print the values in the sheet in range A1:B4
    for value in values:
        print(value)

    # Insert values into the sheet in cell A7
    range_ = 'A7'
    request = service.spreadsheets().values().append(
        spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id, 
        range=range_, 
        valueInputOption='RAW', 
        insertDataOption='OVERWRITE', 
        body={"values":[['This value gets inserted into the cell A7']]})
    response = request.execute()
    print(response)

# METHOD 2 -- using gspread (I prefer this because it's cleaner & does all I need)
import gspread
def hello_pubsub(event, context):
    credentials_filepath = 'default_app_engine_service_account_key.json'
    gc = gspread.service_account(filename=credentials_filepath)
    sh = gc.open("the-title-of-your-sheet-goes-here")
    # Print all values in the sheet
    print(sh.sheet1.get_all_records())
    sh.sheet1.append_row(['This value gets appended to the last row in the sheet'], 
                        value_input_option='RAW', 
                        insert_data_option=None, 
                        table_range=None)
```

Note:
deploy the main.py with:

```
gcloud functions deploy hello_pubsub --runtime python37 --trigger-topic test-topic
```

and don't forget your requirements.txt file

Answer (score 0):

I think you have the dependencies installed globally and you use them. But when you deploy on Cloud Function, your local context is lost and the required library are missing.

Add a `requirements.txt` file in the root directory of your function with this content

```
google-api-python-client==1.8.2
google-auth==1.14.1
```

And deploy again.

Comment: I have updated the requirements.txt within the Cloud Console web interface and redeployed. My Cloud Function still crashes, but I'm not sure why. I just see that it's crashed in GCP Logging. I'm getting:
1) "ImportError: file_cache is unavailable when using oauth2client >= 4.0.0 or google-auth" 2) Traceback File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/googleapiclient/discovery_cache/__init__.py", line 36, in autodetect among many other errors

Comment: Now, you don't have a library problem, it's another problem!

Comment: Excellent, now I'm seeing an HttpError 403 - the caller does not have permission. My default service account has 'owner' role so I'm not sure what's causing this.

Comment: Did you add the default service account email as editor of your gsheet?

Comment: That fixed it, I was adding the wrong service account, I'll answer my own question for future use because there were a few more details I figured out. Thanks Guillaume.